# Google Maps iOS Marker Not Deleting

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using a marker to display the users location in my iOS application. I have it working right now but as the user moves it adds additional markers and does not delete the old one. I cannot use mapview clear because that clears all my markers and there is other markers I do not want deleted in the scene. I will attach the code below. Thanks

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context {
CLLocation *location = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];


        mapIcon = @"largemapicon";

       GMSMarker *myMarker;


        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordi=location.coordinate;
        myMarker = nil;
        myMarker=[GMSMarker markerWithPosition:coordi];
       // marker.snippet = coordinates[@"name"];
        myMarker.map = self.mapView;
        myMarker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

        UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:mapIcon];
        CGSize sacleSize = CGSizeMake(45, 45);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sacleSize, NO, 0.0);
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sacleSize.width, sacleSize.height)];
        UIImage * resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        myMarker.icon = resizedImage;
        NSLog(@"movement");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the marker you need to keep a reference to it outside this method.  If the user's location is always the same marker, simply define it at the class level, and then at the beginning of your `observeValueForKeyPath` method, do the following:

```
myMarker.map  = nil;
```

instead of

```
myMarker = nil;
```

Be sure to move your variable declaration (`GMSMarker *myMarker;`) out of that method as well.  You need it to persist from one  call of `observeValueForKeyPath` to the next (when the user's location is updated).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a marker to show the user's location?  Just turn on the user's location and use the traditional blue dot.